# Rails: How to design a data structure that helps users do reporting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

My Rails app has a `User` model and an `Idea` model. Each user can have many ideas, and each idea belongs to one user (or none). Users take ownership of an idea using the Idea controller's `claim` action, and release ideas using the `release` action.

So far, really simple. But I've just realized I want this to do a bit more, and now I'm not sure how to proceed: Basically, I want users to be able to "report" ideas for being bad/invalid ideas, along with a note specifying the reason for the report.

I would also like to keep track of metrics regarding to claiming ideas -- how long an idea was claimed for before being marked as submitted (it's for managing blog posts), and so on.

In an unrelated question, someone suggested I need a `Claim` model in my app for this sort of complex tracking. This makes sense to me, but I'm really not sure how that model would be structured, and how it would work. Would it be like a log? If so, how would I figure out what's the current idea status for each idea?

Any insights on this would be most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, since you need a log of all user actions its better if you keep Reports and Claims independent.

So, it might look along the lines of

User `has_many` Ideas

Idea `has_many` Claims

Idea `has_many` Reports

Code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :idea
end


class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :desc, :title
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :claim
  has_many :report
end


class Claim < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :status
  belongs_to :idea
end

class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :reason
  belongs_to :idea
end
```

And since, rails migration would add columns for time-stamps. you would be able to calculate the time differences between change of status etc.

Comment: Interesting -- and then when a user releases an idea, for example, then Claims > Status for that idea would become "available"?

Comment: @ezuk yes. I thought so that is how you wanted it.

Comment: I think my Rails may not yet be up to the level of implementing this, but I see the logic in your answer. Thanks, accepting it now!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know ruby but as for the design,

Does reporting an idea as invalid disqualify it?

If not, you can have a Report model in which you include the reported ideas with the Notes. While representing you can have a look at it before rendering the post.